# Three function in R

Tags: r

```
 IS <- function(N,K,sigma,t,r,S_0,a,b,tol){

funct_1 <- function(x){
return((S_0*(exp(-0.5*(sigma^2)*t+sigma*sqrt(t)*x))*(sigma*sqrt(t)-x))+ 
(exp(-r*t))*K*x)
}

bisection_method <- function(a, b, tol, f = funct_1){
if (f(a)*f(b) > 0){
  print("No root found.")
} else
  while ((b - a)/2.0 > tol){
    midpt= (a + b)/2.0
    if (f(midpt) == 0){
      return(midpt) 
    } else if (f(a)*f(midpt) < 0){ 
      b = midpt
    } else
      a = midpt
  }
return(midpt)
}

}
```

The above function will produce nothing for you. My goal that to input the values of "N,K,sigma,t,r,S_0, a,b" and somehow return "midpt" for me. I have searched a lot but could not come up with anything that makes sense. I have many problems, assume that I input everything things, then how the function "funct_1" will output expression, this expression needs to be recalled to the next function "bisection_method} along with the value of a and b then finally obtain the "midpt" value. Any suggestions are really appreciated. Please let me know if there is anything not clear to you at all.

Comment: Be careful about returning a value (`midpt`) that is not always set.  If there is no root found, `bisection_method()` prints but then throws an error (because it can't return `midpt`).

Comment: Please, when you post an answer, give us an example of what input you're trying to use. I'm lacking the context to find out what are appropriate parameters to test the function.

Comment: I am sorry, I am pretty sure about $S_{0}=50$, $r=0.05$, $\sigma=0.2$, $t=1$ and $n=10000$, $tol=0.001$, but not sure about (a,b) where the present the range where the bissection method is going to look into. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Your main function doesn't return anything. It just creates the auxiliary functions and then do nothing. That's why you're getting no output.

Try returning the bisection method with appropriate parameters in your main function instead. I also edited so you get `NULL` output when no root is found.

```
IS <- function(N,K,sigma,t,r,S_0,a,b,tol){

  funct_1 <- function(x){
    return((S_0*(exp(-0.5*(sigma^2)*t+sigma*sqrt(t)*x))*(sigma*sqrt(t)-x))+ 
             (exp(-r*t))*K*x)
  }

  bisection_method <- function(a, b, tol, f = funct_1){
    if (f(a)*f(b) > 0){
      print("No root found."); return(NULL)
    } else
      while ((b - a)/2.0 > tol){
        midpt= (a + b)/2.0
        if (f(midpt) == 0){
          return(midpt) 
        } else if (f(a)*f(midpt) < 0){ 
          b = midpt
        } else
          a = midpt
      }
    return(midpt)
  }
  return(bisection_method(a,b,tol,funct_1))
}
```

Figured out some parameter combination that makes sense:

```
IS(1,1,1,4,5,1,.1,9,10^-4)
[1] 2.000023
```

Comment: Yes, I got something that makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much!